# Disable a command from code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

I have a command that i want to disable depending on the logged user role, is there a way to "block" the command and make it not trigger from code ?

```
<dxmvvm:EventToCommand x:Name="Ev_Comm" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding EditCommand}" EventName="MouseDoubleClick" MarkRoutedEventsAsHandled="True">
```

Something like this:

```
MyViewModel a = (MyViewModel)DataContext;

a.EditCommand.Disable;
```

Thanks

Comment: Presumably `EditCommand` is a class that implements `ICommand`?  You just need to make sure that `CanExecute` returns the correct value depending on your logic.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the answer that i was looking for !